# I want to show a screen while loading resources like share it app uses while scanning near by devices.

Tags: android

https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.howto-connect.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2FTransfer-Large-Files-Using-SHAREit-on-Windows-10-picture-4.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.howto-connect.com%2Ftransfer-large-files-using-shareit-windows-10%2F&docid=UilfBxyrYQNxhM&tbnid=ixAwNKu2iKmZOM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiIvKLQs4bWAhXLtY8KHWLpCnw4ZBAzCAIoADAA..i&w=216&h=384&safe=active&bih=974&biw=1920&q=scanning%20nearby%20device%20screen%20like%20shareit%20android%20app&ved=0ahUKEwiIvKLQs4bWAhXLtY8KHWLpCnw4ZBAzCAIoADAA&iact=mrc&uact=8

I want to show a screen while loading resources like share it app uses while scanning near by devices. Above is the link for the image which shows the example, what i need.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I do this?", what have you tried and what specific problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

You will need :

**Ripple effect background for backgroud ...**

**Round ImageView to display profile picture**

> Create few RoundImages Views in places you want...
>
> When you scanned nearby people set image resourse to *`anything`*